# I have two temporary variables, how can I compare them in PHP?

Tags: php, json, string

I have two temporary variable such as `$tempTeam1` and `$tempTeam2` and both contains different team name between two cricket team. I'm not sure which variable will hold which team as both team name will generate from a JSON file and will go any of temp variable. The variable `$tempTeam1` can hold `India` or `Pakistan` and same for `$tempTeam2`.

For example:

```
$tempTeam1 = "India";
$tempTeam2 = "Pakistan";
```

I have one more variable named `$BattingTeam` and I don't know which team will be batting team though this variable also will come from JSON data. However, `BattingTeam` value must be the same between `tempTeam1` and `$tempTeam1`.

Here I wanted to compare both `$tempTeam1` and `tempTeam2` against `$BattingTeam` variable. Which one between `$tempTeam1` and `tempTeam2` will be the same value with `$BattingTeam` then this value will be set in `$TeamName1` variable and other will be in `$TeamName2`.

Such as, If `$BattingTeam` `India` then `$TeamName1` must be the `India`. And `$TeamName2` will be other one like `Pakistan`.

Sample Input:

```
$tempTeam1 = "India";
$tempTeam2 = "Pakistan";

$BattingTeam = "India";
```

Sample Output:

```
$TeamName1 = "India";
$TeamName2 = "Pakistan";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just use a straight forward `if` statement and compare (one of) the variables to the `$battingTeam`:

```
if ($tempTeam1 == $battingTeam) {
    $teamName1 = $tempTeam1;
    $teamName2 = $tempTeam2;
} else {
    $teamName1 = $tempTeam2;
    $teamName2 = $tempTeam1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes working but sometimes not based on `$battingTeam`. Could you please have a look [here](http://textuploader.com/dto8p) ? Both working and not working data are there.

Comment: @Rezuan Your `$battingTeam` examples have trailing white spaces. You could use `$battingTeam = trim($battingTeam)` to normalize it.

Comment: Yes you are right, this time its working fine. Let me try with few other team. I hope it will work for all.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is really working for all other team. :)